# Unexpected shorthand "background" after "background-repeat"

Tags: css

we got an issue for below block of CSS code

```
.customize_modal.session_timeout .modal-body h1 span{
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f0f0f0), to(#dedede));
}
```

The issue is Unexpected shorthand "background" after "background-repeat". I am not that much of a CSS person and was not able to find out any solution online. Can some one please help me understand this and remediation for this issue. Similar issue was reported for "font" after "font-weight" as well. Please suggest any solution or link. Thanks

Comment: I think using `background-repeat: repeat-x;` after setting `background` will solve it maybe give it a shot

Comment: Works for me no error, check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tunk/pen/tjGdp)

Comment: Error not in console, the CSS code works but there is a code quality tool which we are using.. so this issue was reported in that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background` shorthand or every property by it own:

```css
    background: #dedede -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f0f0f0), to(#dedede)) repeat-x;
```

or

```css
    background-color: #dedede;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f0f0f0), to(#dedede));
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I will give this a try. Also can you please tell me how to modify this code to remove unexpected shorthand "font" after "font-weight" issue.. body {
 background-color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font: normal 700 14px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

Comment: [Font shorthand](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_shorthand.asp). `700` in font stands for `semi-bold`. Change `700` to `bold` and remove `font-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a shorthand property *after* some longhand properties. The shorthand property is... shorthand... anything you do not explicitly specify gets reset. In your case it will overwrite the two properties you declared earlier:

[image: resulting css]

I am guessing this is what the linter is complaining about. I suggest that you use shorthand property first, followed by longer properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can try by Removing any one of Background css property Because Your using Background and Background colour, Then Background repeat only works for Image.In case You want to repeat linear gradient add 'repeating-' before the word linear gradient